# Pick $B$ s.t. $BA$ is positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a generic invertible matrix, i.e. not necessarily symmetric and generally indefinite.

Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix such that $BA$ is positive definite, i.e. $x^TBAx > 0$ for all $\|x\|=1$. $B$ should, ideally, be computationally inexpensive to derive.

For example, $B = A^T$ satisfies the request for all $A$, and is computationally inexpensive since it just requires a transpose operation. On the other hand, $A^TA$ is generally worse conditioned than $A$.

If $A$ is symmetric, then given $A = V\Lambda_A V^{-1}$ any matrix $B = V\Lambda_B V^{-1}$ such that $\Lambda_B \Lambda_A > 0$ satisfies the request. This could in principle be used to ameliorate the problem's conditioning down to $\kappa = 1$, but is computationally expensive as it requires to compute $A$'s eigendecomposition.

Is there a "name" for these matrices and/or rules on how to derive them, s.t. computing $B$ is not computationally expensive and, on the other hand, the condition number $k$ of $BA$ is worsened less than in the $B=A^T$ case (for which $\kappa(A^TA) = \kappa(A) ^2$)?

Comment: For any positive definite matrix $M$, we can just take $B = MA^{-1}$

Comment: You're right, but that is computationally expensive as it requires to compute the inverse. I was looking for computationally inexpensive ways (such as $B = A^T$), maybe I should rephrase the question. Thanks anyways!

Comment: It might be helpful if you could give us some more context. That is, maybe you could explain what it is that you're trying to accomplish by doing this premultiplication. Is there something wrong with just using $B = A^T$ every time?

Comment: I added some information. I am dealing with dynamical systems where I can use an arbitrary matrix $B$ to stabilize a system $A$. Using $B = A^T$ is the easy pick, but worsens the dynamical response as error and bandwidth are linked to $\kappa(BA) = \kappa(A)^2$ if $B = A^T$. So I was wondering if there were other matrices that could be used to "stabilize" the system (i.e. making the loop gain matrix positive definite), without worsening its performance. However, the whole point of the system is to exploit its dynamics to compute matrix inverses, so I can't use an inverse as stabilizer.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a [preconditioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner). All of the options referred to on the wiki page are such that $\kappa(BA)$ has a lower condition number, but I don't think that they make it so that $BA$ is positive definite.